# Magento 2 - How to call Helper function via Block

Tags: magento2, blocks, phtml, helper

**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="vendor" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>Vendor</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="module" translate="label" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>Module Name</label>
            <tab>vendor</tab>
            <resource>Vendor_Module::module_configuration</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="modulestatus" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Module Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="display_text" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Display Text</label>
                    <comment>This text will display on the frontend.</comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <module>
            <general>
                <enable>1</enable>
                <display_text>Hello World</display_text>
            </general>
        </module>
    </default>
</config>
```

**Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $objectManager;

    const XML_PATH_MODULE_GENERAL = 'module/general/';

    public function __construct(Context $context, ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager, StoreManagerInterface $storeManager)
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->storeManager  = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getConfigValue($field, $storeId = null)
    {

        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue($field, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId);
    }


    public function getModuleStatus($code, $storeId = null)
    {

        return $this->getConfigValue(self::XML_PATH_MODULE_GENERAL  . $code, $storeId);
    }

}
```

**Block/Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data;

class Index extends Template
{
    public function __construct(Context $context, StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, Data $helperData)
    {        
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_helperData = $helperData;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getModuleStatus()
    {

        return $this->_helperData->getModuleStatus();
    }

}
```

To fetch values, I am using below code in my template file, it displays the module enable/disable status but does not display text

```
echo $block->getModuleStatus();
echo $block->getModuleStatus('display_text');
```

- How could I call helper functions via block in template file ?
- How could I add `ifconfig` condition in xml to load block ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it resolved by changing code to below

**Block/Index.php**

```
 <?php

    namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

    use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
    use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
    use \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
    use \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data;

    class Index extends Template
    {
        public function __construct(Context $context, StoreManagerInterface $storeManager, Data $helperData)
        {        
            $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->_helperData = $helperData;
            parent::__construct($context);
        }

        public function getModuleStatus($code)
       {

        return $this->_helperData->getModuleStatus($code);
        }

    }
```

Fetch value using below

```
echo $block->getModuleStatus('modulestatus');
echo $block->getModuleStatus('display_text');
```

To use it via `xml`

`ifconfig = section_id/group/field`

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" ifconfig="config_path/group/field" name="contact-us-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact Us</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">contact</argument>
        </arguments>
</block>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have defined the function in your helper file you need to pass the config path that you want to retrieve.

In your **block**

```
public function getModuleStatus()
{
    return $this->_helperData->getModuleStatus('modulestatus');
}
```

In your **template** file you can directly call the function

```
echo $block->getModuleStatus();
```

How to use ifconfig in your xml you can refer the [contact module](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Contact/view/frontend/layout/default.xml)

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" ifconfig="contact/contact/enabled" name="contact-us-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact Us</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">contact</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
```